# Cloning a repository results in a timeout

Tags: windows, mercurial

I upgraded my OS to Windows 7 and installed mercurial, but I can't seem to be able to clone any remote repository. Windows Firewall is disabled and I don't have a third-party firewall. I even tried to launch the command prompt as administrator. No matter what I do, I always get this Operation timed out error. Any ideas?

```
c:\Users\Alfred>hg clone http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/ hgrepo
abort: error: Operation timed out
```

Comment: I assume you can ping the host?

Answer (score 0):

Hrm, what does the output look like when you include `--debug` and `--verbose`?

Also, what happens if you clone over ssh using this command line?

```
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/ hgrepo
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine when I clone it just now. I guess Bitbucket simply had a small problem. In such a case, the best reaction is to log onto the `#bitbucket` IRC channel on `irc.freenode.net` -- StackOverflow is not a very good support forum, especially for transient problems like this.